# How to include any enum value in property with Linq where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Linq statement below, where calendarParams.RegisteredType is a nullable int.
In the second to last line where I set the value to null if there is no value,
how can I set it to any (enum) value, if the value is null?

```
var registrants = await _dbContext.Registrants
    .Where(p => p.EventDate.Month == calendarParams.Date.Month 
        && p.EventDate.Year == calendarParams.Date.Year 
        && p.UserId == userId 
        && (p.RegistrantType == (calendarParams.RegisteredType.HasValue ? (RegistrantType)calendarParams.RegisteredType : null)))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intention correctly, you could alternatively change the second to last line in your original expression to the following:

`&& (!calendarParams.RegisteredType.HasValue || p.RegistrantType == (RegistrantType)calendarParams.RegisteredType))`

If `calendarParams.RegisteredType` does not have a value (--> the first part of the predicate is `true`), it simply skips the `p.RegistrantType == (RegistrantType)calendarParams.RegisteredType` filtering step.

To make it clearer, perhaps, you could assign the first expression to a variable:

```
var allowAllTypes = !calendarParams.RegisteredType.HasValue;

var registrants = await _dbContext.Registrants
    .Where(p => p.EventDate.Month == calendarParams.Date.Month 
        && p.EventDate.Year == calendarParams.Date.Year 
        && p.UserId == userId 
        && (allowAllTypes || p.RegistrantType == (RegistrantType)calendarParams.RegisteredType))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding you can not do that inside LinQ as not accept any kind of integrated function or structure. So the more easy way to me is get over the problem outside the LinQ

```
int? myvalue = calendarParams.RegisteredType.HasValue ? (RegistrantType)calendarParams.RegisteredType : null;

var registrants = await _dbContext.Registrants
    .Where(p => p.EventDate.Month == calendarParams.Date.Month 
        && p.EventDate.Year == calendarParams.Date.Year 
        && p.UserId == userId 
        && p.RegistrantType == myvalue)
    .ToListAsync();
```

By the way I don't understand what are you doing the "HasValue" check if the default value is null. But I do exactly the same only to show the principle. In this case "int?" is the "int nullable" (I don't know if I understand the type of RegistrantType, but I think you get the idea)

Comment: I can't set registeredType to null as it will check for that, think of this as a filter, if no value is provided then all values are used. I posted an answer below.

Comment: @user1186050 ooooooooohhhhhhhhhhhh!!! I understand now. You can do easily do that in SQL, but not in LinQ. The more easy way is duplicate the query with different condition and use one or another query by the condition evaluated before the query.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do. Here is my answer.

```
var query = _dbContext.Registrants
       .Where(p => p.EventDate.Month == calendarParams.Date.Month && p.EventDate.Year == calendarParams.Date.Year && p.UserId == userId)
       .Select(f => f);

        if (calendarParams.RegisteredType.HasValue) {
            query = query.Where(p =>  p.RegistrantType == (RegistrantType)calendarParams.RegisteredType);
        }

        var registrants = await query.ToListAsync();
```